# Google maps custom control callback

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

When I've added a custom control to Google Maps, I want to add a tooltip via a jQuery plugin.
Is there a callback available for when the control is loaded in the DOM?

Code to add the control can be found here: 
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/control-custom

Edit:
I found a similar question from 2011:
[Is there an event for when google maps controls are loaded?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6945947/is-there-an-event-for-when-google-maps-controls-are-loaded)

Is there any solution for this yet?

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem by adding the idle listener (once):

```
google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(this.gmap, 'idle', _.bind(function() { 
    this.activateTooltip(); 
}, this));
```

It waits until the DOM is loaded with custom controls included.